# sorting issue on bootstrap tagsinput

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ for tagsinput.

I did not find any method for sorting.

for eg. when i press D, it will show this result >

[image]

but it should be like this > 
[image]

How can i sort suggested list properly ?

Code (bootstrap tagsinput)

```
<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington" data-role="tagsinput" />
<script>
var citynames = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: {
    url: 'assets/citynames.json',
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(cityname) {
        return { name: cityname }; });
    }
  }
});
citynames.initialize();

$('input').tagsinput({
  typeaheadjs: {
    name: 'citynames',
    displayKey: 'name',
    valueKey: 'name',
    source: citynames.ttAdapter()
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: That really depends on which typeahead you are using and how you initialise the tagsinput.

Comment: @davidkonrad I have added 3rd image for code. or see here > http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/  : typeahead

Comment: please read again. i am using  bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples plugin.  when i try to enter any word ( 1st screenshot), it's showing incorrect order. 

2nd screenshot is my requirement ( correct order ) 

That's all